# Crystal Reports fields won't align

Tags: crystal-reports, alignment, crystal-reports-xi

I have several items that I want to line up.  The Width and Height of all fields match.  Usually I just use the Align, but it's making it worse.  My out of line field which is slighly lower, moves way up, way out of line (with align tops)

So I tried using the Size and Position to set it manually.  Several objects have a Y of 0.056, but my last one has 0.061.  I change the last one to 0.056 and save it.  It doesn't appear to be different, and when I look at it again, it's still 0.061. (When I used align, it went up to 0.028!)

I do NOT have Snap to Grid set (my grid size is 0.083).  (Nor does turning on Snap to Grid make them align.) The fields have exactly the same formatting.  But unless I can magically make them align by hand, they refuse to align.  Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already done a lot of the regular troubleshooting steps. One more ting that I sometimes do is to select all the fields I want to align, then use the arrow keys and move them up into the section above and then back down into their original section. That usually puts them all into the 0 position. If it dosn't work with all of them selected, try each one separately.

Comment: I know it's not pretty, but sometimes it's all you can do to get those dang fields to align!